# modify mesh of existing model

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to modify an existing simple mesh but am having trouble.  It is a disk amulet with a setting ring in the center (extruded and beveled) with a "Gem" setting in the center.  Right now everything is a disk with the gem being half a sphere.  I would like to turn the setting disk and the gem into an oval shape rather than the disk shape while the outside disk stays the same.  I have imported the model and have selected the  points of the mesh that represent the setting disk but do not know how to modify the shape.  Any help would be appreciated.[image: Amulet showing ring to be made oval]

Comment: With what you already have selected in the image - try turning on proportional editing (hotkey - letter O) and scale on the X axis only (S + X). You can adjust the size of the edit influence by scrolling the mouse wheel. You also may end up needing to hide some parts of the mesh you don't want to affect first. There are also different edit "shapes" that can be accessed from the proportional edit menu at the top center of the viewport (next to the snapping options), but I think the default should work for you as a start.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.  Here's an easy one.

- Deselect everything.
- Select the vertex at the very top of the hemisphere
- use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>–<kbd>+</kbd> to add to the selection until you've selected all of the vertices you want to include.  (Alternatively you can use circle or lasso select.)

You'll have a selection that looks like this, roughly:

[image: selection to make oval]

- scale in the X direction to fix the X axis of the oval (shortcut <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>)

[image: scaled in the X direction]

- scale in the Y direction to fix the Y axis of the oval (shortcut <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>)

[image: scaled in the Y direction]

Of course, you may need to scale in only one direction to get the shape you want.